# Different icons between xaml/emulator & real device

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm developing a universal app for windows, with VS Ultimate 2013 & Caliburn.Micro.
I noticed that XAML or Emulator and real Nokia device show different icons, while same code work properly for windows app.  In particular "like" button (57759 value http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbol) becomes an "heart" in the real device (see image).

Here the code:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
  <CommandBar>
    <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
      <AppBarButton Icon="Dislike" IsCompact="False" Label="Dislike"/>
      <AppBarButton Icon="Like" IsCompact="False" Label="Like"/>
      <AppBarButton Icon="LikeDislike" IsCompact="False" Label="LikeDislike"/>
    </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
  </CommandBar>    
 </Page.BottomAppBar>
```

[image: xaml VS real device]

Someone has the same problem? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue where the phone and desktop fonts are different, and the designer and emulator use the desktop font. It is being investigated for a fix in future versions.

The typical solution is not to do anything and use the Windows Phone icons on Windows Phone. If you specifically want the thumb icons on Windows Phone then you can provide your own icon images as a [PathIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.pathicon.aspx) or [BitmapIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.bitmapicon.aspx) rather than using the SymbolIcon or FontIcon.